# When is this line part of this plane..

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

given is:

$ g: \vec x = \frac{1}{15} \begin{pmatrix}
 14 \\  13 \\  7 \\ \end{pmatrix} + r* \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\2 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$ E: ax_1 * 2x_2 + x_3 = 4 $

What is "a", when $ g \in E $ ?

I tried putting two points of g into E without getting the desired result.
I also tried to argue that $ \vec n * \vec u = 0 $ (90° between the two vectors..

Maybe you can help :))

Comment: If you really mean that the line is to be a subset of the plane, you should write $g \subset E$ rather than $g \in E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's try one point of $g$. You know the point $g(0) = (x_1, x_2,x_3) = \tfrac1{15}(14,13,7)$ lies on the line $g$, since it corresponds to the parameter value $r=0$. If this point also lies on the plane $E$, then 
$$
a\left(\frac{14}{15}\right) + 2\left(\frac{13}{15}\right) + \left(\frac{7}{15}\right)  = 4
$$
We can solve this to find a value of $a$.

But if we do the same thing with the point $g(1)$ corresponding to $r=1$, then we get a different value for $a$.

This shows that there is no value of $a$ that will cause both $g(0)$ and $g(1)$ to lie on the plane. So, there is no value of $a$ that will cause the line to lie in the plane.

Comment: Hi, but when I use a second point of g (with r = 1) I get a different "a" - what now?

Comment: Puzzling. How about you double-check your calculations while I think about possible errors in the reasoning.

Comment: Corrected my answer. Apologies for the previous drivel.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. I certainly was very confused by what the task said: "What value does a have, so that ..." << I interpreted this as "There IS such a value: Find out which one!" :)

Comment: Yeah, a bit of a trick question. Varying $a$ is rotating the plane. Generally, when rotating a plane, there is very little chance that you will be able to get it to contain a given line. Asking for a plane to contain a line is a **very** restrictive condition.

Comment: Hello once again: I tried drawing line and plane with a 3D-Plot-Programm. I now wonder if it is possible to find out the line, around which the plane can be rotated (by varying $a$) ?

Comment: The plane is always parallel to the vector $(0,-1,2)$. You can see this because its normal $(a,2,1)$ is perpendicular to this vector. But the distance from the plane to the origin is also varying. So, tracing its variation as $a$ changes is not easy, AFAICS. I don't think the plane is simply rotating around some fixed line. 3D plotting might give you some insight. Please post pictures in another answer if you find anything illuminating.